# Convert non-fixed with text file to CSV with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to convert this file to CSV with a python script. Here is what I have so far:

```
import re

f = open("Run_TR20_QT_base_iter1_gage_lakTest.dat", "rt")

fout = open("Lake_Gage_Data.txt", "wt")

for line in f: 
    fout.write(re.sub('\s+', ',', line))
```

This replaces all whitespaces of any length with commas, but now I need a insert a newline after each line is edited in the input.

Comment: what do you mean by "_... insert a newline after each line is edited in the input._"? `fout.write(re.sub('\s+', ',', line) + '\n')` ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I was looking to keep the line structure the same, if that makes sense... Is there a better way to say this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert space-separated to csv, it might be better to use the actual `csv` module rather than regex. For example:

```
import csv

with open("your_input.dat", "r") as f, open("your_output.csv", "w") as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for line in f:
        writer.writerow(line.split())
```